# Unable to install NDES

Tags: ad-certificate-services

I have enterprice CA running on a Windows 2008 box. I am trying to configure NDES on a windows server 2012 R2. I followed all the instructions word by word from this blog: http://windowsitpro.com/security/setting-network-device-enrollment-service but it fails with the following error:

> Failed to install RA certificates. The requested certificate template is not supported by this CA.
>
> 0x80094800 (-2146875392 CERTSRV_E_UNSUPPORTED_CERT_TYPE)
>
> [Failed to install RA certificates 0x80094800 (-2146875392 CERTSRV_E_UNSUPPORTED_CERT_TYPE)][2]

Comment: You should use official documentation provided by vendor: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9063.network-device-enrollment-service-ndes-in-active-directory-certificate-services-ad-cs.aspx apparently you missed CEP encryption certificate template.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in Microsoft KB [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/281260/a-certificate-request-that-uses-a-new-template-is-unsuccessful), this error may occur

> if the certificate enrollment request is using a recently-created
>   certificate template. When a new template is added to the CA, the
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER cache is immediately updated but the
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE cache is not immediately updated. The HKEY_LOCAL_
>   MACHINE cache is updated in the next 15 minutes if the CA or the
>   domain controller are on the same computer, and in the next 10 minutes
>   if the CA or the domain controller are in a distributed configuration.

Possible resolution assumes manual updating the certificate template cache. It can be done by editing the registry. Please refer to the article I've provided above to learn more about this procedure.

This material may be useful for you as well: https://ammarhasayen.com/2010/12/14/the-requested-certificate-template-is-not-supported-by-this-ca-error-0x80094800/

Hope it helps!